# OpenCL vs CUDA performance on Nvidia's device

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpgpu

I coded a program to create a color lookup table. I did it in CUDA and OpenCL, from my point of view both programs are pretty much the same, i.e. use the same amount of constant memory, global memory, same loops and branching code, etc.

I measure the running time and CUDA performed slightly better than OpenCL. My question is if using CUDA+NvidiaGPU is faster than OpenCL+NvidiaGPU because CUDA is the native way of programming such GPU?

Could you share some links to info related on this topic?

Comment: Can you share the info - how fast is one vs the other? Can you compare the generated assembly codes (PTX) of the kernels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCL and CUDA are equally fast if they are tweaked correctly for the target architecture. However, tweaking may negatively impact portability.

Links:

- http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1005/1005.2581.pdf
- http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=6047190&tag=1

Comment: That's what I thought that both should have very similar performances, but in both papers you posted apparently CUDA runs always faster than OpenCL just by porting code. We can achieve equal performances if we tweak the code, though.